# VBA - Open Hyperlink to another sheet in the current document

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, worksheet

My Excel-Worksheet contains some cells with hyperlinks to other sheets in the same document.

How can I go to this new sheet or save it in a variable using VBA ?

Hyperlinks(1).Follow did not work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you fully qualyfing the `Hyperlinks` collection (i.e. `Sheets("yourSheet").Range("yourRange").Hyperlinks(1).Follow`? Are you sure the hyperlink you want to follow is the first one? What does _did not work_ mean? It doesn't go to the page, it gives you an error, it does nothing?

Comment: P.s. if you need to execute the action of changing sheet, I would rather suggest `yourSheet.Activate` or `yourSheet.Select`, much easier and not relying on hyperlinks that the user might decide to delete.

Comment: I need to parse elements in the other Sheet. 
.Follow gives an error with internal hyperlink (what I need)

Answer (score 0):

Below code give you addresses as message boxes, you can write whatever you want within there.

You need to be careful about if the link is within the same workbook it is recorded as `SubAddress`, if it is an external link it is recorded as `Address`

```
Sub LinkFind()
    For Each lnk In ActiveSheet.Cells.Hyperlinks
        MsgBox lnk.SubAddress
    Next
End Sub
```

Following code does not make any sense but just to show you visiting procedure:

```
Sub LinkVisit()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet '<- or Sheets("Sheetname")
    For Each lnk In ws.Cells.Hyperlinks
        lnk.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```